# Keep Gnuplot auto refresh window inactive

Tags: gnuplot

I am running a simple script, that reads data from a file and plots it. My problem is that I reread and replot the data, as the file continuously changes. Whenever I use `refresh` the plot window becomes active again, which I would like to prevent. I would like the plot to be updated in the background. Is this possible?

My sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set datafile separator ","
plot "data.dat" using 1:3
pause 1; refresh; reread;
```

Comment: For anybody trying to use this technique: The 'refresh' command was invalid when I tried it. It worked when I replaced it with 'replot'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This depends on what terminal you're using.  `wxt`, `x11` and `qt` support a `noraise` option:

```
set term x11 1 noraise
```

This should allow it to stay in the background.

Comment: `set term qt noraise` for those using Qt. =)